# Socketio.emit("reload") does absolutely nothing

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

For my web interface i use flask-socketio to reload automatically the page when i add some content to it

Here is interesting part of my server code :

```py
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")
...
def receive_data(conn):
    data = ''
    while True:
        try:
            ...
                socketio.emit('reload')
                ...
def start_receiving_images():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    ...
    threading.Thread(target=receive_data, args=(conn,)).start()
    ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=start_receiving_images).start()
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5005, debug=True)
```

And here is the script which i include in my web page :

```js
let socket = io.connect(document.domain + ':' + location.port);
console.log(socket);

socket.on('connect', function(){
   console.log('Successfully connected!');
});
socket.on('reload', function(data) {
   console.log("Received reload request", data)
   window.location.reload();
});
```

Unfortunately, despite having restarted the program and the browser interface several times, socketio.emit("reload") does absolutely nothing on the browser side, even though I have proof through print statements that the line is executed several times. Does someone has some idea of the problem ?